# Free variables in derivation systems

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I work relative to a fixed first-order language $L$. As usual I call those formulas which do not contain free variables sentences. There are several derivation systems for first-order logic. For example, in Goldrei's *Propositional and Predicate Calculus* a derivation of $\psi$ relative to a set $Ax$ of sentences is a list of **formulas** $\phi_1,....,\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n = \psi$ and each $\phi_j$ is either an axiom or can be obtained from the previous formulas via some rules. One such rule is for example that $\phi_j$ can be $\forall x\phi_k$ when $k<j$ and $x$ is free in $\phi_k$. There are also other derivation systems which manipulate sequents $$\phi_1,...,\phi_n\vdash_{\underline x} \psi_1,...,\psi_m$$according to rules, but here again the $\phi_i$ and $\psi_j$ are **formulas**.

Is this use of formulas instead of sentences essential, or just convenient? Are there derivation systems which only manipulate sentences and have (a reasonable amount) of rules which tell how to produce new proven sentences from already proven ones?

Motivation: I am working with a complicated semantic, and I can only define truth-conditions for closed formulas. I want to check that my semantic is sound, but I can not just check the rules blindly, because they are of the form "when those formulas are derivable, then so is that formula".

Comment: Convenience... You have the rule for eliminating universal quantifiers (UI): if you want to avoid free variables, you must have enough individual constant to instantiate the universally quantified formulas with closed terms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you have a reference for an "list style" deductive system (I think they are called axiomtic) in which only sentences appear?

Comment: See BBJ, [Computability and Logic](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Computability_and_Logic/kKPA1DF-g44C) page 168: A sequent $\Gamma \Rightarrow D$ consists of a finite set of *sentences* $\Gamma$...

Comment: For Hilbert-style, see [Enderton](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Mathematical_Introduction_to_Logic/dVncCl_EtUkC), page 112: derivations are sequences of *formulas*, but "the logical axioms are then all generalizations of wffs of the following forms ..."